# Design control law

Tags: control-theory

Consider the function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is continuously differentiable and strongly convex. Let $x^*$ to be the unique global minimizer of $f$.

Assume that $L_1\|x\| \leq \nabla f(x) \leq L_2 \|x\|$. Consider the dynamic system $\dot{z} = A z + B u$ with $(A,B)$ being stabilizable. Design a controller $u$ depending on $x,z$ for the following dynamics such that $x(t)$ and $z(t)$ both converge to $x^*$ from any initial state $x(0), z(0)$: \begin{align*}\dot{x} = -\nabla f(z),\quad \dot{z} = A z + B u.\end{align*}

Comment: You need more conditions. If $A$ is Hurwitz and $B=0$, then $(A,B)$ is trivially stabilizable, but $z\to 0$ in all cases, and we can always choose $x(0)$ so that $x \not\to x^*$.

Comment: There is one more condition: There exists $u^ *$ such that $Ax^ *   + Bu^ *   = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the variable given by $e=z-x^\ast$. Taking its derivative, you get 
\begin{equation*}
\dot{e}=\dot{z}=A(e+x^\ast) + Bu.
\end{equation*}
Now, assuming that $B$ is invertible, with the coordinate change $u=v-B^{-1}Ax^\ast$ the last equation yields
\begin{equation*}
\dot{e}=Ae+Bv.
\end{equation*}
Since $(A,B)$ are stabilizable, there exists a feedback law $\phi=-Ke$ such that the origin is globally asymptotically stable for
\begin{equation*}
\dot{e}=(A-KB)e.
\end{equation*}
This implies $e(t)\to0$. Consequently, $z=x^\ast$ and $x=x^\ast$.